# Верно отобразить ссылку на фотографию из цикла

Tags: php, массивы

```
<?php foreach ( $colors_array as $other => $colors_array) { ?>
    <option data-price="<?php echo $priscolors_array[$other]?>"value="<?php echo $prisimages_array?>"><?php echo $colors_array?></option> 
 <?php } ?>
```

Переменная `<?php echo $prisimages_array?>` выводит фотографию такого вида

```
value="<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>/storage/home/widgets/prisforms/prisforms.tpl.php</b> on line <b>52</b><br />
Array"
```

Хотя по умолчанию задана ссылка на фото в переменной, как быть?
В шаблоне виджета, вывод такой `$prisimages_array    = explode("\n ", $prisimages);`
P/S из value я получаю ссылку на фото.

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашел, неверно выводил фотографии.

```
data-price="<?php echo $priscolors_array[$other]?>"
```